# postback doesnt refresh contents of testbox or gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I realy need help for this. I am using `AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer` and using `ASP.NET Framework 4.0`. Gridview,textbox and button are placed in TabContainer on asp page. When I press button postback does happen but its not binding gridview to datatable and textbox contents are also not updated.

I debug the code and found when i press button postback does happen and content does fill up in gridview and textbox value also assigned with new value. but values doesnt display on the page. I dont know why its happening. please help.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsPostBack)
  {
      if (ListBoxCustomer.Items.Count != 0)
      {
          int[] _selectedItems = ListBoxCustomer.GetSelectedIndices();
          string _comma = "";
          string _custID = "";
          InitializeConnection();
          if (_selectedItems.Length != 0)
          {
              foreach (int i in _selectedItems)
              {
                  _custID = _custID + _comma + ListBoxCustomer.Items[i].Value;
                  _comma = ",";
              }
              if (custObj != null)
              {
                  //DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
                  DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
                  GridViewCustomer.Visible = true;
                  GridViewCustomer.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                  _ds = custObj.GetSelectedCustomers(1, _custID);
                  GridViewCustomer.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
                  GridViewCustomer.DataBind();

                  TextBoxTest.Text = GridViewCustomer.Rows.Count.ToString();
                  TextBoxTest.Text = "test";
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Do the GridViewCustomer and GridViewCustomer placed in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: no its not in UpdatePanel its in TabContainer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the DataBind code is never being reached.  Have you set some breakpoints to make sure the if-statements aren't blocking you?  That is... Is ListBoxCustomer.Items.Count **definitely** not zero... Is custObj **definitely** not null?

Where do you assign a value to custObj?

Comment: yes i verified that Databind code has reached. all objects are filled and ListBoxCustomer is not null and gave me selected customers. custObj is assigned in InitializeConnection() function.

Comment: +1. It looks like `custObj` is nowhere assigned, it is null. So the last if condition is not met (not reched)

Comment: yes i verified during debugging that Databind code has reached. all objects are filled and ListBoxCustomer is not null and gave me selected customers. custObj is assigned in InitializeConnection() function and i test custObj was not null and took me to GetSelectedCustomers() fucntion.

Comment: Does this line from your code fill your textbox?  "TextBoxTest.Text = GridViewCustomer.Rows.Count.ToString(); "  You'll have to comment-out the following line of course (where you set it to "test").

Comment: textbox and gridview loads fine if i call same code at first time pageload. but contents doesnt refresh when postback happend. please help.

Comment: textbox doesnt fill with "test" as well. textbox is still empty.

Comment: @sonia: so if you remove `if (IsPostBack)` condition completely still no success (just for test)?